# CSS Responsive Design - How to keep class and id selectors from using previous code

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I am not exactly sure how to ask this question.  I am new to responsive design and understand the flow down, but I don't want to use the flow down on my menu.  It is broken into 3 sizes and the mobile size, I don't want sub-menus and need it at 100% width.  How do I block the information from the previous id and class selectors.

```
/*------------menu */
nav {font-family: "BenchNine", "PT Sans Narrow", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
text-transform: uppercase;
width:960px;
height: 43px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
/*background:#0084FC;*/
border:0px solid #FFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
z-index:10;

}


/*nav ul {list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0 5px; } */
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}



nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}


nav ul {margin: 0;padding: 0 5px;list-style: none;position: relative;display: inline-table; z-index:1;}


nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}


nav ul li span { width:425px;}


nav ul li {
    float: left; position: relative; padding: 0px; top:0px;border-top:0px solid #0082f8;
}


    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #025287;
    }


        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }


    nav ul li a {font-size: 20px; color: #B3DBFF; display: block; padding: 54px 10px 6px 10px; margin-bottom: 0px; z-index: 10; position: relative; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;}


nav ul ul {
    background: #0082f8; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%; 
}


    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 0px solid #0082f8;
        border-bottom: 0px solid #0082f8; 
        position: relative;

    }


        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 10px 40px;
            color: #fff;
        }   


            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #025287; color:#fff;
            }


nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

This is the css for the menu in the responsive css file.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

nav {width:100%;background:none;height:auto;margin: 0px auto 15px auto;}
nav ul li {float: none;background:#000;text-align:center;padding-bottom:0px;margin-top:5px;}
nav ul li span {clear:}
nav ul li:hover {background: url('../images/menu-bg-act_mob2.png') repeat-x;}
nav ul li a{margin-bottom : 0px;}
nav ul li a{margin-bottom : 0px;}
```

Comment: Your question is still not clear to me.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to help me verify what you're saying?  Also, I might suggest spending some time playing around with the responsive grid in something like Bootstrap or Foundation to help give you experience with the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but it sounds like you need to override some existing style declarations.

You should be able to do this by making more specific declarations.

E.g.:

`html nav { margin: 20px }` will override `nav { margin: 10px }`.

Check out [Andy Clarke's CSS Specificity Wars](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) for more on the subject.

Comment: Where it says
`nav ul ul {
    background: #0082f8; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%; 
}

`


I don't want it to call up any of those in mobile

Comment: Do you mean, RATHER than overriding them, you simply don't want them accessed?

Comment: I just made the visibility:hidden and that seems to take care of it.